# Retrive the Shipping method and shipping rates programmatically

Tags: shipping, model, shipping-methods

I had overwriten the shipping Model , I need a carrier rates from the carrier codes for the further calculation in model class.

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 6):

Try this code

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart');
$address = $cart->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
$shipping = Mage::getModel('shipping/shipping');        
    $result=$shipping->collectRatesByAddress($address)->getResult();
    $newrates = array();
    $newrateCodes = array();
    $shippingRates=$result->getAllRates();
    foreach ($shippingRates as $rate) {
        if ($rate instanceof Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Result_Error) {
            $errors[$rate->getCarrierTitle()] = 1;
        } else {
            $k = $rate->getCarrierTitle().' - '.$rate->getMethodTitle();
            $k = $rate->getCarrier() . '_' . $rate->getMethod();

            if ($address->getFreeShipping()) {
                $price = 0;
            } else {
                $price = $rate->getPrice();
            }

            if ($price) {
                $price = Mage::helper('tax')->getShippingPrice($price, false, $address);
            }

            $newrates[$k] = $price;
            $newrateCodes[$k] = $rate->getCarrier() . '_' . $rate->getMethod();
        }
    }
```