# Magento 2 Retrive the Shipping method and shipping rates programmatically

Tags: shipping-methods, magento-2.1.7

My current magento version is 2.1.7

I need exactly this but in magento 2

[Retrive the Shipping method and shipping rates programmatically](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26288/retrive-the-shipping-method-and-shipping-rates-programmatically/29768#29768)

Comment: Programatically as in from PHP, or JavaScript? What have you tried? You need to be more specific.

Comment: PHP, I don't understant knockout js, so I need this in php